# CruiseControl.net and Subversion

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net

My project is not noticing when subversion gets updated.  I have the exact same setup working on another server.  This is a virtual server.

Here is my log file after I have made a commit.  It seems like ccnet can see that there is an update but it just ends by saying no modifications detected.

```
2009-12-17 10:34:47,000 [MyProjectName Continuous Integration:INFO] Project: 'MyProjectName Continuous Integration' is first in queue: 'MyProjectName Continuous Integration' and shall start integration.
2009-12-17 10:34:47,000 [MyProjectName Continuous Integration:DEBUG] Checking if C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\MyProjectName Continuous Integration\WorkingDirectory is a svn working folder
2009-12-17 10:34:47,000 [MyProjectName Continuous Integration:DEBUG] Starting process [svn] in working directory [C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\MyProjectName Continuous Integration\WorkingDirectory] with arguments [log svn://myserver.com/trunk -r "{2009-12-16T21:19:48Z}:{2009-12-17T17:34:47Z}" --verbose --xml --username myusername --password mypassword --non-interactive --no-auth-cache]
2009-12-17 10:34:47,203 [444:DEBUG] [MyProjectName Continuous Integration svn] <?xml version="1.0"?>
2009-12-17 10:34:47,203 [444:DEBUG] [MyProjectName Continuous Integration svn] <log>
2009-12-17 10:34:47,203 [444:DEBUG] [MyProjectName Continuous Integration svn] <logentry
2009-12-17 10:34:47,203 [444:DEBUG] [MyProjectName Continuous Integration svn]    revision="1427">
2009-12-17 10:34:47,203 [444:DEBUG] [MyProjectName Continuous Integration svn] <author>myusername</author>
2009-12-17 10:34:47,203 [444:DEBUG] [MyProjectName Continuous Integration svn] <date>2009-12-16T18:34:50.148524Z</date>
2009-12-17 10:34:47,203 [444:DEBUG] [MyProjectName Continuous Integration svn] <paths>
2009-12-17 10:34:47,203 [444:DEBUG] [MyProjectName Continuous Integration svn] <path
2009-12-17 10:34:47,203 [444:DEBUG] [MyProjectName Continuous Integration svn]    kind=""
2009-12-17 10:34:47,203 [444:DEBUG] [MyProjectName Continuous Integration svn]    action="M">/trunk/MyProject/MyFile.cs</path>
2009-12-17 10:34:47,203 [444:DEBUG] [MyProjectName Continuous Integration svn] </paths>
2009-12-17 10:34:47,203 [444:DEBUG] [MyProjectName Continuous Integration svn] <msg></msg>
2009-12-17 10:34:47,203 [444:DEBUG] [MyProjectName Continuous Integration svn] </logentry>
2009-12-17 10:34:47,203 [444:DEBUG] [MyProjectName Continuous Integration svn] </log>
2009-12-17 10:34:47,312 [MyProjectName Continuous Integration:INFO] No modifications detected.
```

Comment: The `-r "{2009-12-16T21:19:48Z}:{2009-12-17T17:34:47Z}"` looks suspicious.

Comment: I set this up yesterday and it checks subversion every two minutes.  Should the dates be closer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have any modifications, you just think you do.  This is a classic problem with Subversion that many CC.NET users fall prey to.  Look more closely at the log and you'll see:

- The SVN command is being executed at 2009-12-17 10:34:47 (presumably you're in a GMT-7 timezone)
- The range of modifications being checked is from 2009-12-16 21:19:48 GMT to 2009-12-17 17:34:47 GMT - *i.e.*, in the last 20 hours, more or less
- The only reported revision is from 2009-12-16 18:34:50.148524 GMT - **BEFORE** the start of the range.

In short, `svn log` lies, or at least fib a bit, in that it **ALWAYS** reports at least one change, even if it is older than the specified range.  See [SVN bug #1642](http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=1642) if you want the details.  The odds are that it will never be fixed - the last comment is from 2004.

This is covered in the CC.NET doc:

> **CruiseControl.NET doesn't see my
>   changes**
>
> The Subversion interface depends on
>   the clocks of the CruiseControl.Net
>   and Subversion servers being set
>   within a small difference. Due to a
>   long-standing Subversion bug (Bugzilla
>   #1642) that appears unlikely to ever be fixed, CruiseControl.Net must
>   filter the list of modifications
>   returned by Subversion, looking for
>   only those that fall within a specific
>   time range. When the clocks of the two
>   servers are significantly different,
>   the filter may ignore modifications
>   that should not be ignored. To prevent
>   this problem, keep the clocks of the
>   two servers set as closely together as
>   possible.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix this by updating to the latest ccnet.  They use revisions instead of dates to update the trigger.  after that it all just worked.

Comment: in greater than two days time i will accept my own answer when stack overflow allows me

Answer (score 0):

Is your virtual server running with a future time?. Perhaps you should try some time synchronization.

Comment: I have tried time sync and it doesn't seem to work.  If I put the cruise control.net server time in the distant past will this ensure the change is seen?

Comment: I moved the date 1 year into the past just to see if it would pick up on anything... nothing